# Encountered error "ReferenceError: $ is not defined" Using rails-react

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I am facing problem when making prerender: true, any way to fix it?

`Encountered error "ReferenceError: $ is not defined" when prerendering Store with {"data":{"results":708,"total_pages":59,"previous_page":null,"next_page":2,"designs":`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might need to require the jquery package. I'm running an isomorphic server rendered app and had to include `var $ = require ('jquery')` (after installing it -- `npm install --save jquery`) on all the components that reference jQuery.

Comment: For further understanding: The issue is that when pre-rendering your JS, `react-rails`  doesn't have access to `document` or the `Global` scope ([see Docs](https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails#server-rendering)). I assume you include `$` through the document and not your package manager so it's only present globally within the browser.